# Parsing Ajax loaded HTML content in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, internet-explorer

I have seen similar questions around, but none of them seem to have answers that help my case...

Basically, I want to load some HTML in using `$.ajax()` (Which is on a different domain), and have it parsed into it's own DOM, so I can apply attributes and manipulate HTML in my actual window DOM.

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'http://example.com/index.html',
    dataType: 'html',
    crossDomain: true,
    cache: false,
    success: function(data) 
    {
        var src = $('body img', data).first().attr("src");
        //also tried: var src = $('body', $(data)).first().attr("src"); 
        $('#someDiv img').attr("src", src);
    }
});
```

Where an example HTML file is:

```
<html>
<body>
    <img src="someurl"></img>
</body>
</html>
```

It works in Firefox, but not IE, no matter what I try, whenever I try to parse and read, it returns null.
Any suggestions?

EDIT:

It appears there was some ambiguity with my question. The issue is the parsing, not the AJAX. The AJAX returns the html string correctly, but jQuery fails to parse it.

EDIT 2:

I found a 'solution', but it isn't nearly as nice as I wanted it to be, it chopping and sorting through the HTML string, and extracting data, rather than applying it to a DOM. Seems to run efficiently, as I can predict the order of data.

Boiled down, it is something like this:

```
var imgsrcs = new Array(5);
var searchItem = '<img src="';
for (var a=0; a<5; a++) {
    var startLoc = data.search(searchItem) + searchItem.length;
    for (var i=0; i<data.length; i++) {
        if (data.charAt(startLoc + i) == '"')
            break;
        imgsrcs[a] += data.charAt(startLoc + i);
    }
    data = data.substring(startLoc + i, data.length);
}
$('.image').each(function(i) {
    $(this).attr("src", imgsrcs[i]);
});
```

Fairly ugly, but I solved my problem, so I thought I may as well post it.

Comment: I wonder how you managed to do AJAX across domains in firefox, when Same Origin Policy prevents you. Are you using CORS?

Comment: @Joseph `jQuery.support.cors = true; ` Yes.

Comment: @gdoron HTML string returned from AJAX

Comment: Try this: `$(data).find('body img:first').attr('src')`. does it work?

Comment: just to confirm, *"it returns null"* - is "it" the `data`? or the `src`?

Comment: @Joseph the `src`. `data` contains the html string, which works.

Comment: @gdoron That returned undefined...

Comment: try `console.log($('body img', $(data)))` and see if it contains anything.

Comment: @Joseph `data` is out of scope, but `$('body img', $('<body><img></img></body>'));` returns the correct data object.

Comment: @Der I know you said it does work, but what does `console.log($('body img', $(data)))` return? I'm just checking if it's jQuery failing to parse or is there something in `data` that makes it fail to parse.

Answer (score 2):

This is a Same Origin Policy problem.

The `crossDomain` flag in jquery's `ajax` function doesn't automatically make cross domain requests work in all browsers (not all browsers support CORS). Since you're requesting this from a different domain, a normal request won't actually be able to read the data (or even make the request).

Normally, for json data, you can do JSONP, which is what the `crossDomain` often flag enables. However, JSON is unique because it can be natively read in javascript. Since HTML cannot be read, you'd need to wrap it in parseable javascript to employ a trick like JSONP.

Rather than do that on your own, though, I'd highly suggest that you look into the easyXDM library in order to do cross domain messages like this. You'd essentially open up a hidden iframe on the other domain, and pass messages back and forth between the parent and the hidden frame. And, since the hidden frame is on the *same* domain as the html, it will have no problem ajaxing for it.

http://easyxdm.net/wp/

Comment: I'll give the library a shot, thanks. I think I should clarify that the data IS returned, but the parsing fails.

Comment: Correct, it's trying to parse as JSONP, I suspect, which it is not.